# Do creature effects trigger every time they move base?

Tags: smash-up

Do creature effects trigger every time they move base, or just the first time they enter play?

For example, if I play Invader, gain 1 VP, then play Invasion and move it to a second base, do I gain another VP?

[image: Invader, Minion, 3, Gain 1 VP.]

Comment: I just stated an example effect in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Invader grants a victory point when it's *played*, not when it's *moved*.

> **Play:** You play a card
>   when it’s one of the
>   free cards you get in
>   step 2, or any time an
>   ability specifically says
>   that you’re playing it. A
>   card’s ability happens
>   when you play it. When
>   cards are moved, placed,
>   or returned, they’re not
>   being played, and their
>   abilities don’t happen.
>
> **Move:** This lets you
>   move a card from one
>   location to another.
>   Moving a card does
>   not count as playing it.
>   Minion abilities do not
>   happen when you
>   move a card.